# How to revert this NotificationManager.Policy method?

Tags: java, android

I have a method to allow Alarms when Do Not Disturb is on in Android P. I have a switch button to toggle on the Alarms and all works fine, but the problem is I don't know what method to use to toggle the Alarms off.

This is my code:

```
    private void allowAlarms() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        notificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(
                new NotificationManager.Policy(NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS,
                        NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY,
                        NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY));
    }
    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
}
```

I have tried cancelling the notification manager, but this does not work and the alarm still rings.

```
notificationManager.cancel(0)
```

I have also tried simply calling the Priority only code again, but this does not work either.

```
assert mNotificationManager != null;
                    mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
```

I want Alarms to go back to being blocked by default in Priority Only mode, when I toggle the switch off. However, whatever I try, the alarm still rings after I toggle it off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the Policy before you change it, with `NotificationManager.getNotificationPolicy()`, and set it to this policy when your done, together with `NotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this:

```
 notificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(
            new NotificationManager.Policy(NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS | NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_CALLS | NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_MESSAGES,
                    NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY,
                    NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY));
```

Meaning that if you want the policy to have a filter for messages or calls you have to set that flag in the category part of the policy. Otherwise it'll always allow no calls or messages.